# How to extend mongoose.model class in Typescript 2

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to export my own mongoose model and implement my own query methods, something like this:

```
export function modelFactory<T extends Document>(model: Model<T>) {
  return class Base extends (model as Model<Document>) {
    find(conditions: any, isLean: boolean = false) {
      return super.find(conditions).lean(isLean).exec();
    }
}
```

This way my model has the customized `find` method and other model methods defined from my schema's static methods. But I get an error saying `Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Document'`. Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, have been solving the same thing some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276117/add-definition-to-existing-module-in-typescript